# Match Documents based on Nested Array Values and Count Unique

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB Collection which has Documents in Given format,

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595f5661f34ae7b2adee31bc"),
    "app_userUpdatedOn" : "2017-03-09T12:01:07.615Z",
    "appId" : 31625,
    "app_lastCommunicatedAt" : "2017-03-09T12:18:53.067Z",
    "currentDate" : "2017-03-09T12:19:28.626Z",
    "objectId" : "58c14850e4b0b2406992b29e",
    "name" : "APPSESSION",
    "action" : "START",
    "installationId" : "98088f6641a0fa79",
    "userName" : "98088f6641a0fa79",
    "properties" : [
        [
            "userid",
            "98088f6641a0fa79"
        ],
        [
            "app_os_version",
            "6.0.1"
        ],
        [
            "app_installAt",
            "2017-03-09T12:01:01.307Z"
        ],
        [
            "app_model",
            "SM-J210F"
        ],
        [
            "app_lastCommunicatedAt",
            "2017-03-09T12:18:53.067Z"
        ],
        [
            "app_carrier",
            "Jio 4G"
        ],
        [
            "app_counter",
            1
        ],
        [
            "app_brand",
            "samsung"
        ],
        [
            "app_lib_version",
            "1.0"
        ],
        [
            "app_app_version",
            "3.0.2"
        ],
        [
            "app_os",
            "Android"
        ]
    ],
    "date" : "2017-03-09"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("595f5661f34ae7b2adee31bd"),
    "app_userUpdatedOn" : "2017-02-05T07:38:32.866Z",
    "appId" : 31625,
    "app_lastCommunicatedAt" : "2017-03-09T08:09:05.342Z",
    "currentDate" : "2017-03-09T12:19:28.806Z",
    "objectId" : "58c14850e4b06ec88ecaa9c6",
    "name" : "APPINSTALL",
    "action" : "START",
    "installationId" : "eef436554fbdf4ac",
    "userName" : "eef436554fbdf4ac",
    "properties" : [
        [
            "userid",
            "eef436554fbdf4ac"
        ],
        [
            "app_os_version",
            "5.1"
        ],
        [
            "app_installAt",
            "2017-02-05T11:20:49.809Z"
        ],
        [
            "app_model",
            "Micromax Q465"
        ],
        [
            "app_lastCommunicatedAt",
            "2017-03-09T08:09:05.342Z"
        ],
        [
            "app_carrier",
            "JIO 4G"
        ],
        [
            "app_counter",
            1
        ],
        [
            "app_brand",
            "Micromax"
        ],
        [
            "app_lib_version",
            "1.0"
        ],
        [
            "app_app_version",
            "3.0.2"
        ],
        [
            "app_os",
            "Android"
        ]
    ],
    "date" : "2017-03-09"
}
```

I want to Fetch the Count and Unique Count of the Documents where **currentDate** lies in between, **startDate** and **endDate**, name is x (eg. APPSESSION), Containing multiple Properties Nested Array (like ["app_installAt","**This can be any value instead of null**"] ,["app_model","**This can be any value instead of null**"], and so on... ), Group By **userName**

Previously i have created a Query in which Nested Array Both Element are Known, and it is as follows

```
db.testing.aggregate(
      [
            {$match: {currentDate: {$gte:"2017-03-01T00:00:00.000Z", $lt:"2017-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"},name:"INSTALL"}},
            {$match: {properties: ["app_os_version","4.4.2"]}},
            {$match: {properties: ["app_carrier","telenor"]}},
            {$match: {properties: ["app_brand","Micromax"]}},
            {$group: {_id: "$userName"}},
            {$count: "uniqueCount"}
      ]
);
```

But i am unable to find the Data where i know only 0th index of Property Data Nested Array.

Please do Help.

Thanks in Advance.... :)

Comment: Can I point out that the only way the data would look like this is because of an error in the code updating to it in the first place. Would it not be more logical to fix the code writing it incorrectly instead? This is completely the wrong way to store this.

Comment: Yes i know, but the Algorithm writing the data is the same and the Data is so huge that changing the Structure of Data is also not feasible as it contains TB's of Data.

Comment: If it's Terrabytes of data then all the more reason to fix it. Right now you cannot effectively use an index to aid in the query results. Where all the criteria was actually based on arrays with keys and values of specific paths, then an index would be far more effective and speed results. Anyhow, I have already answered the question with the query for the current format.

Comment: I got the answer to my question, your answer below did my work.
i am working to improve the structural changes required, and to migrate the existing data source.

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query for this is essentially the use of [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) for the multiple conditions to match in the array and then use [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) and [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) to match the individual array elements.

For example to match and count the first document supplied in your question "only" the parameters would be:

```
db.testing.find({
  "currentDate": { 
    "$gte": "2017-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
    "$lt": "2017-03-10T00:00:00.000Z"
  },
  "properties": {
    "$all": [
      { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_os_version","6.0.1"] } },
      { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_carrier", "Jio 4G"] } },
      { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_brand", "samsung"] } }
    ]   
  }
})
```

With `.aggregate()` then you put the whole query into a single [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) stage as in:

```
db.testing.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "currentDate": { 
      "$gte": "2017-03-09T00:00:00.000Z",
      "$lt": "2017-03-10T00:00:00.000Z"
    },
    "properties": {
      "$all": [
        { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_os_version","6.0.1"] } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_carrier", "Jio 4G"] } },
        { "$elemMatch": { "$eq": ["app_brand", "samsung"] } }
      ]   
    }
  }},
  { "$group": { "_id": "$userName" }
  { "$count": "unique_count"
])
```

So [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) in this context is going to examine each "inner" array and see if it matches the supplied conditions, which we give in argument as an "array" to the [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/eq/) operator.

The wrapping [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/) means that "all" the provided [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) conditions "must" be met in order to fulfill the query conditions. And that is how the selection gets made with this type of structure.

If you needed to adjust one of those then the "inner" match is using the element of the array. So on the key it would use the `"0"` for the index position. i.e:

```
   { "$elemMatch": { "0": "app_os_version" } },
```

Comment: and What about the case in which i know "app_os_version" in array and not "6.0.1", i want to take all results after filter from properties array of array in which i know only the array 1st element and not the second

Comment: @Shashank Use the "index" position inside the `$elemMatch`. Added to answer to demonstrate.